# get cloud storage file from firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'd like my firebase web app to upload a file, and I'd like to have a cloud function that discovers this file and creates a database object based on its contents. Here's the last variant of many I've tried...

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.onStorageFinalize = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
  const storage = new Storage();
  const bucket = storage.bucket('my app's storage bucket name');

  return bucket.file(object.name).download(function (err, contents) {
    // problem: no err, no contents, set doesn't run just a warning about promises!
    const result = `got err=${err}, contents=${contents}`
    return db.collection('myCollection').doc().set({
      result: result
    })
  });
});
```

The very small file is uploaded, and this trigger runs. When I don't attempt getting the contents of the file, the database object is created fine (with a literal string instead of the file result).

But when I run it as shown above, first I get a warning that says:

> onStorageFinalize: Function returned undefined, expected Promise or
>   value

That's wrong.  The doc for `file().download()` says it returns a promise.... and, more importantly, the database `set()` doesn't run.

I am astounded by how confusing and obscure (and I think wrong?) the google docs are on this seemingly mainstream use case.  Much obliged if someone can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you will see in the documentation of the Google Cloud Storage Node.js Client for the [`File`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File?authuser=0#download) object, you have to omit the callback in order for the `download()` method to return a Promise.

The way you call the `download()` method you are not returning a promise, hence the error you receive.

So you need to do as follows:

```
return bucket.file(object.name).download()
    .then(data => {
        const contents = data[0];
        // Do something with the contents constant, e.g. derive the value you want to write to Firestore

        return db.collection('myCollection').doc().set({
           value: ......
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like your answer sends a callback, too?  The arrow function?  But will try it now... appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry there is an error in my answer, I forgot the then(). I gonna adapt it.

Comment: I see the link you provided (very helpful), but I am trying to understand the param sent to the promise `contents = data[0];`  what is data, what is the "blob" in data[0], and how can I see the plain text from my file?

Comment: I sure appreciate your help!!  I found a doc for blobs and used `data[0].toString()`